# MIPS array Input from user

Tags: arrays, mips

I have a question.
How to put input that has been entered by the user into an array? The user put the input in other function and I want to it as my input in my array.

Answer (score 0):

First, make an array — for example, a global array is declared in the `.data` section, using a label, and reserving storage perhaps with `.space 40` to reserve 10 words of storage.  If the array is after strings (for prompts and prints) using `.align 2` ahead of the global array to make sure the array is properly aligned in memory.

```
        .data
        ...
        .align 2
array:  .space 40
```

We can also use dynamic storage for the array via syscall 9, `sbrk`, or, use stack space by lowering the stack pointer.

Second, we do array references by computing the address of the element of interest and using a load or store to that address.  The address of interest can be computed by the formula `array + index * scale`, where `scale` is the byte size of the elements of the array (i.e. 4 for word arrays).  For example, let's assume an array index, i, is in register `$t0`, and we want to reference array[i].  Multiplying by 4 (which is the second power of 2) is done with a shift instruction.

```
la $t1, array      # load base address of the array into $t1
sll $t2, $t0, 2    # multiply i by 4 to scale for element size of 4 bytes each
addu $t2, $t2, $t1 # sum base address and scaled i -- $t2 now points to array[i]
lw $t3, ($t2)      # fetch from memory the value referred to by address in $t2
```

or for assignment, similar just change the load to a store, e.g. array[i] = t3

```
la $t1, array      # load base address of the array into $t1
sll $t2, $t0, 2    # multiply i by 4 to scale for element size of 4 bytes each
addu $t2, $t2, $t1 # sum base address and scaled i -- $t2 now points to array[i]
sw $t3, ($t2)      # store value into memory at array[i]
```

Use these sequences inside a loop that increments the index, i.  Note that we can keep the address of the array in a register for the duration of the loop, so the `la` pseudo instruction can be before and outside of the loop.

We can also use pointers instead of indexing.  For that, modify the register that refers to the array.  Instead of computing `array + index * scale` each time, increment the register, here `$t0`, by 4 within the body of the loop, to point to the next element in the array.

```
loop:
    ...
    lw -or- sw $t3, ($t0)
    ...
    addiu $t0, $t0, 4
    ...
    j loop
```

The other parts of the body of the loop will need to do the prompt and user input operations.